# Windows / Ubuntu - отключение доступа к системным файлам Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, файловая-система, dual-boot

На машине установлены две ОС- windows и Ubuntu.

В каталоге /mnt/win находятся файлы Windows.

```
ls /mnt/win 
ANG0                    linux.bin            Recovery.txt
boot                    Menu                 $Recycle.Bin
bootmgr                 MSOCache             sbrfbin
bootsqm.dat             noid.mif             System Volume Information
Documents and Settings  noid_tm.mif          TEMP
found.000               PerfLogs             Users
found.001               ProgramData          Windows
found.002               Program Files        Локальные документы
hiberfil.sys            Program Files (x86)
Linux                   Recovery
```

Как отключить возможность доступа к системным файлам Windows?
Не повредит изменение стики-бит прав на каталоги/файлы работе системы?
Или есть более "красивый" метод для решения этого кейса.
Спасибо

Comment: *отключить возможность доступа к системным файлам Windows* запретить читать? менять? только их или все файлы?

Comment: вообще по максимуму ограничить доступ к виндовым файлам, проблема в том, что необходимо ограничить и права локального администратора

Comment: А смонтировать, но RO - не устроит? или отключить в принципе?

Comment: "А смонтировать, но RO - не устроит?" - это как ?

Comment: " или отключить в принципе? " - вторая система нужна

Comment: *это как ?* Это когда читать можно, а записывать нельзя. *вторая система нужна* Это к чему было сказано?

Comment: " Это когда читать можно, а записывать нельзя" - то есть перемонтировать ? mount dev/sdx /mnt/win -ro ? " Это к чему было сказано" - это к отключить в принципе было сказано

Comment: *то есть перемонтировать ?* Есссно... если надо - запомнив это дело на будущее (только емнип `-o ro`). *это к отключить в принципе было сказано* Вообще-то имелось в виду отключение доступа к тому. Ну или размонтирование, другими словами.